# Categorize or divide enum?

Tags: c++, enums, categories

I have an enum like this:

```
enum objects {
     BAG_BOOK,
     BAG_PEN,
     BAG_FOLDER,
     HOUSE_DOOR,
     HOUSE_FLOOR,
     HOUSE_TABLE
};
```

Now I want to be able to select an object (using a uint8) and query which category it belongs to (bag or house). 
The problem is that I sometimes add a few entries in the enum and therefore I can't say that it is from 0-2 the category bag and from 3-5 house.
Does anyone have an idea how I could solve it or how I could categorize the enum?

PS: the real enum is a bit more complex than the example

Comment: Use **Scoped enumerations** instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But could you explain it? Because I don't have any idea how I could use scoped enums for my intent

Comment: @TimoSpielberger that's called `enum class` in C++

Answer (score 0):

**"I sometimes add a few entries in the enum"** 
How are you doing this exactly? You can't change enums at runtime, so you must be adding the items statically. In this case, you know the range of indices of BAG and HOUSE.

You can use maps, which will serve your purpose the best. Try this -

```cpp
    map<int, string> my_map;

    my_map[14] = "bag";
    my_map[9] = "house";
    my_map[67] = "something else";

    //enumerate all items in your map
    for(auto x : my_map){
        cout << x.first << " " << x.second << endl;
    }

    //check a specific item in the map
    cout << my_map[9] << endl;
```